# Como fazer o empty() aceitar o valor 0?

Tags: php

Tenho um cadastrado onde verifico se os campos forma preenchidos, em alguns dos campos pode-se apenas colocar os dígitos de 0 a 9.

Porém se a pessoa coloca 0 da como se ela não tivesse preenchido nada.

Isso se da pelo verificação do `empty()`. Um pequeno trecho da verificação está ai.

```
}else if (empty($idade)){
```

Comment: Pode fazer `}else if (empty($idade) || $idade == 0){`. Mas se explicar melhor que tipos de valor `$idade` pode ter podemos ser mais claros na ajuda...

Comment: idade pode ter apenas dois dígitos. Ex: 34. Porém quero que o 0 também seja aceito.

Comment: Se utilizar `(empty($idade) || $idade == 0)` vai ocorrer problemas, você esta verificando se a idade é vazia ou se a idade é igual a zero. O problema dele acredito que ocorre quando a idade é uma idade valida, porém ele reconhece como vazia por ser zero.

Comment: isso dai mesmo @Pedro Henrique

Comment: @ivanveloso, você escreveu nos comentários: "Porém quero que o 0 também seja aceito." É isso que pretende?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode melhorar a expressão utilizando algo como:

```
else if (empty($idade) && $idade != 0)
```

Isso vai verificar se a $idade esta em vazia e não é zero.
Porém é melhor considerar uma validação mais especifica como os [is_int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) do PHP.

Comment: O Ivan escreveu: `Porém quero que o 0 também seja aceito`

Comment: O trecho "else if (empty($idade) && $idade != 0)" não resolveu, porem substitui o empty pelo is_int. Ai resolveu.

Comment: @Sergio `empty(0)` é true.

Comment: @bfavaretto, hmm... verdade, erro meu. Nesse caso a minha resposta está errada e a pergunta faz ainda menos sentido... :/

Comment: Não está nada errada `empty(0)` é *true*, mas `0!=0` é *false*, a condição é falsa, ou seja, não entra na verificação do *empty* quando a idade é 0.

Answer (score 2):

Estou atrasado, mas espero poder ajudar alguém:

Esbarrei em um caso onde é necessário verificar um índice de um `array`, usando os outros exemplos, você pode receber o erro `Undefined Index`. Geralmente uso o `empty()`, para testar valores em `arrays` pois ele não dá um `warning` se o índice não existir.

No caso `0` é um valor considerado `empty` e se você tentar acessar um índice de um `array` que não existe, o `warning` antes mencionado vai ser lançado.

Portanto cheguei na seguinte solução:

```php
if (empty($array['age']) && @$array['age'] !== 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Idade não informada.', 400);
}
```

Note que usei o operador `@`, que suprime os `warinings` naquela linha, **[que NÃO é uma prática recomendada](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)**, mas que neste caso, apenas uma parte simples e isolada do código é afetada e não trará problemas.

No lugar de `@$array['age'] !== 0`, você pode pensar em usar `isset($array['age'])`, mas o `isset` considera o valor em `$array['age'] = null` como `false`.

É uma pena que no PHP ainda por padrão dá esse tipo de problema (por exemplo o JavaScript permite acessar índices não definidos), mas que pode ser alterada nas configurações, o grande problema é não tratar o índice antes de realizar alguma ação, como acessar o método de um índice indefinido, por isso, sempre tome cuidado com esse tipo de manipulação de dados, que pode gerar bugs inesperados na aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer verificar se o valor é vazio com o `empty`, porém quer aceitá-lo caso seja igual a 0.

no caso teria de se verificar primeiro se o valor é igual a 0, já que a verificação vai  ocorrer da direita para a esquerda; caso contrário, o empty retornaria true ao verificar primeiro "0" como um valor vazio.

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma de solução seria:

```
else if (empty($idade) || count(ltrim($idade," ")) < 1)
```

O que esta verificação faz é:

- Verifica se a variável `$idade` é vazia;
- Ou se sua extensão é menor do que 1 caractere (sem contar espaços)